# TRegEx::IsMatch is always false

Tags: c++, regex, c++builder

I have small function for validating columns in StringGrid after user cancelled editing it.

```
void validateColumn(int column, const UnicodeString regexp, TStringGrid* sg) {
   int i;
   UnicodeString value;
   bool correct = true;
   for(i = 1; i < sg->RowCount; ++i) {
        value = sg->Cells[column][i];
        correct = TRegEx::IsMatch(value, regexp);
   }
   if(!correct) {
        ShowMessage("Wrong!");
   }
}
```

Here is my regular expressions and sample data they used for:

```
const UnicodeString regGroup = "\d{6}"; // 510101
const UnicodeString regDate = "^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[-., /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[-., /.](19|20)\d\d$"; // 02.06.1998
//... function call in TForm1::StringGrid1SetEditText event
if(ACol == 1) {
    validateColumn(ACol, regDate, StringGrid1);
    }
if(ACol == 2) {
    validateColumn(ACol, regGroup, StringGrid1);
}
```

So, variable `correct` always becomes `false` and "Wrong!" screen appears, but on online regex testers it matches. Maybe my regexps is a little bit incorrect?

Comment: I think you need to mask your backslashes: `"\d{6}"` becomes `"\\d{6}"`

Comment: @Schrieveslaach: and `\d\d` needs to be `\\d\\d`.

Comment: @fobo66: When your loop ends, your `correct` variable specifies the result of only the **last row** in the grid. You need to `break` the loop as soon as `IsMatch()` returns false, or at least use `correct = correct && TRegEx::IsMatch(value, regexp);` instead of `correct = TRegEx::IsMatch(value, regexp);`. Either way, this will allow `correct` to be false if *any* row fails validation.

Comment: @Schrieveslaach thanks for advice, it helps.

Comment: @fobo66, I will post an answer for that. Do you mind to mark it as correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to mask the backslashes in the regular expression. Otherwise they will be handled as masks for special characters, like newline `'\n'`:

```
const UnicodeString regGroup = "\\d{6}"; // 510101
const UnicodeString regDate = "^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[-., /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[-., /.](19|20)\\d\\d$"; // 02.06.1998
```